# Recognize if Excel file is opened on OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I have OneDrive as a shared location for all employees.
I have Excel files located on that location for various employees.
I have macros that save a single file as a database from three files for three users.

The problem is that if any of the three users happen to save at the same time while another user is trying to save, then a copy of that file - db is created on server as another session.

I thought of checking if that single file is open, so that only if that file is closed the other user can save it.

- When an Excel file is opened, an auto temp file is created named (~$filename) in hidden files.
- The code checks if a temporary file (~$xxx) exists, so it returns "busy" if open and returns "available" if closed.
- ***The problem here is that this temp file (~$xxx) is only available on users' local machines not on OneDrive.***

How do I recognize active sessions on each file on server?

```vb
Public var As String
Private myFS As Object
        
Sub IterateFiles()
        
    Set myFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    CheckFolder "D:\Onedrive\MyWorkspace\Operation\Emp"
End Sub
        
Sub CheckFolder(ByVal path As String)
    Dim myFolder As Object
    Dim myFile As Object
    Dim mySubFolder As Object
    Dim myFiles
        
    Set myFolder = myFS.Getfolder(path)
    Set myFiles = myFolder.Files
        
    For Each myFile In myFiles
        If InStr(myFile.Name, "~$Employees") > 0 Then
            var = myFile.Name
        End If
    Next
        
    If var <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "server busy"
    Else
        Debug.Print "server available"
    End If
        
    Set myFolder = Nothing
    Set myFiles = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm without recent experience re your problem but want to offer my tuppence worth since it's a slack Saturday afternoon. Microsoft has been aware of your problem for years, if not decades (by now). Even without other users on my machine I get notifications that a file is "open by another user" all the time and "do I want to get a read-only copy?" Therefore I think you must have a setting on your OneDrive somewhere which expressly permits several users to access files at the same time. I suggest you look for and disable that permission.

Answer (score 0):

mmm well for me you could try to use Checkin (for workbook object)and checkout (for workbooks object)